# Iframe positioning

Tags: html, iframe, position, css-position

This is iframe code of google translate.

```
<div id="contentframe" style="top: 160px; left: 0px;">
<iframe src="/translate_p?hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;prev=_t&amp;sl=auto&amp;tl=en&amp;u=http://yahoo.co.jp/&amp;depth=1&amp;usg=ALkJrhjrVT6Mc1tnruB-zgrtu9cyQ1bSeA" name="c" frameborder="0" style="height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;bottom:0px;">&lt;/div&gt;
</iframe></div>
```

I tried to do something similar with the same div and iframe tags but the html page does not end up like google translate.

```
<div id="contentframe" style="top: 160px; left: 0px;">
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com" style="height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;bottom:0px;">&lt;/div&gt;
</iframe></div>
```

The iframe appears right at the top of the page instead of appearing 160px later, as specified by the div.

I'm not sure what is wrong here with my code, which is almost the same as the Google code.

Edit:
The adding of the position:relative to the  tag is not suitable as a solution. It shrinks the div into a bar with a small height. It also means that the exact position of the  with respect to the page cannot be specified as a result.

Answer (score 8):

It's because you're missing `position:relative;` on `#contentframe`

```
<div id="contentframe" style="position:relative; top: 160px; left: 0px;">
```

`position:absolute;` positions itself against the closest ancestor that has a `position` that is not `static`. Since the default is `static` that is what was causing your issue.

Comment: Do you know why Google Translate's page not have the position:relative but still works?
Edit: Just tried putting position:relative in the <div>. It doesn't work :(

Comment: I'm not sure what part of Google Translate you're referring to, your `iframe` is part of your page and Google Translate is completely contained and separate to yours.

Comment: Google Translate is a page implemented by Google. Google Translate as a page, does not have position:relative in the <div>.

Adding the position:relative also causes the div to shrink to a bar with small height.

Answer (score 3):

you have to use this css property,

```
 position:relative;
```

use it for your #contentframe div tag

Comment: John already mentioned that position relative is not suitable as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the css style property

```
position:relative;
```

to the div tag , it works ,

Answer (score 1):

you should use position: relative; for one iframe and position:absolute; for the second;

Example:
for first iframe use:

```
<div id="contentframe" style="position:relative; top: 100px; left: 50px;">
```

for second iframe use:

```
<div id="contentframe" style="position:absolute; top: 0px; left: 690px;">
```