# How to position iframe (calendar) inside php echo statement?

Tags: php, html, css, iframe

I am trying to place a calendar on the **top right corner** of my page:

```
<?php
    echo 'other html 1';
    echo 'other html 2';
    ....

    // Calendar
    echo '<iframe 
              src="https://calendar_link"
              style = "border: 0;
              position: absolute;
              width: 500;                  // This does not have any effect, why?
              height: 500;                 // This does not have any effect, why?
              top: 160px;                  // This does not have any effect, why?
              frameborder: 0; 
              scrolling: no;">
          </iframe>';
?>
```

The calendar is displayed and I can alternate its size, but I can't figure out how to move it to an arbitrary position. It always appears below other html code regardless of what I'm doing.

Note that:

- I can't change php to html file, as this page is part of a larger system
- I don't want to rely on other echo statements. It would be nice to fix this without the need of figuring out what's happening in rest of that file.
- I would be happy to move style things specific to `iframe` out to a separate css file.

**How to place `iframe` wherever I want?**

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587823/iframe-positioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are positioning your iframe, you should use **position** property and as you want your iframe appearing top right corner of the page then you should also use **top** and **right** properties to achieve this result

```
<?php

            echo '<iframe 
                  src="http://cuassistant.tk/"
                  style = "
                  border: 0;
                  position: absolute;
                  display: block;
                  width: 500px;                  
                  height: 500px;             
                  top: 0px; 
                  right: 0px;
                  frameborder: 0; 
                  scrolling: no;">
              </iframe>';
```

Checkout the following link [CSS position property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

**Note : since iframe is an old thing in html, there are so many attributes are deprecated. You should better take a look at those at the following page [Iframe Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)**

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work in my case: http://ml693.user.srcf.net/ is a page where calendar gets displayed at the bottom regardless of what I make top equal to.

Comment: all right, i have updated my answer and checked it out and it worked out. You should give it a try.